# Setting the context's connection name depending on the user that logs in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

This used to be a `Web Forms` application and I'm rewriting it in MVC.

The connection name is stored in the user's details and depending on the user, I need to pass a different connection name.

In `WebForms` this was solved by setting a `Session` variable in `Global.asax` and then every time the context is needed, I'd create the context in a using statement, passing the `Session` variable in the context constructor like this:

```
using (IAccountContext db = new MainContext(Session["cn"]) { }
```

In `MVC` I'm declaring the context as a field:

```
public class ManageController : BaseController
{    
    private readonly IAccountContext _db = new MainContext(ConnectionName);

    // other actions

}
```

and I can't pass the non-static `Session` variable. I tried using a `BaseController` that the rest of the controllers would inherit and tried initializing the `ConnectionName` in the constructor and in the Initialize method but neither worked

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public BaseController()
    {
        using (var db = new UserDbContext())
        {
            ConnectionName = (db.Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId())).ConnectionString; 
        }
    }

    public static string ConnectionName { get; set; }

    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        using (var db = new UserDbContext())
        {
            ConnectionName = (db.Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId())).ConnectionString;
        }
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to avoid using a `using` clause in every single `Action` and rely on `MVC` to dispose the context in the `Dispose` method.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

**EDIT:**

Francesc Castells's answer looks promising, but when using the `BaseController` the `User.Identity.GetUserID()` call throws a NullReference exception. If the ManageController inherits from the original `Controller` it works just fine. Am I forgetting to initialize something else?

This is the Stacktrace

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   TestProj.Web.Controllers.BaseController..ctor() in E:\TestProj.Web\Controllers\BaseController.cs:14
   TestProj.Web.Controllers.ManageController..ctor() in E:\TestProj.Web\Controllers\ManageController.cs:60

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +119
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +232
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +11
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +55

[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'TestProj.Web.Controllers.ManageController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +178
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +76
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +88
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +194
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +103
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly with getting the ConnectionName in the constructor of the BaseController?

Comment: I get this exception: The argument 'nameOrConnectionString' cannot be null, empty or contain only white space

Comment: So what is missing is the connection string for the UserDbContext? I understand that this one is unique, so it shouldn't be a problem. Just pass the connection string or connection string name in new UserDbContext(<connectionStringName>). Alternatively define a connection string in the web.config called UserDbContext.

Comment: Nah, the UserDbContext works fine, I don't know how to fetch the `ConnectionString` parameter in time to pass it to the MainContext. I get the ArgumentException when I try to instantiate the MainContext

Comment: Ah, ok. I understand now what you mean. But why don't you simply do _db = new MainContext(ConnectionName); in your controller's constructor instead that directly in the field? this way the ConnectionString will be initialized before being used. It is technically the same, but the order of execution will be the right one

Comment: You have a whole different issue then. The problem is in the Identity configuration. Your user is not authenticated.

Comment: It is. I have another controller that doesn't inherit the `BaseController` but requires authentication and I can access that one. I added `[Authorize]` to the `BaseController` but that didn't work...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93885/discussion-between-francesc-castells-and-gregoryhousemd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RequestContext` in `Initialize()` method.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected string _connectionName;
    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        if(requestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            using (var db = new UserDbContext())
            {
                _connectionName = db.Users.Find(
                    requestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId())
                    .ConnectionString;
            }
        }
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
    }
}
```

Now you could simply inherit your controllers:

```
public class ManageController : BaseController
{
    private IAccountContext _db          

    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
        _db = new MainContext(_connectionName);
    }

    public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
        // now you have access _db variable
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if(disposing)
        {
            _db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is I'll be using different context interfaces in different controllers, that's why I want the context declaration in the main class and not the `BaseController`

Answer (score 0):

Create the MainContext in the constructor, after the BaseController constructor has been executed and the ConnectionName initialized.

```
public class ManageController : BaseController
{    
    private readonly IAccountContext _db;

    public ManageController()
    {
          // Here the base constructor has already been executed, so ConnectionName has the right value
         _db = new MainContext(ConnectionName);
    }

   // other actions

 }
```

But I would suggest a different approach: Use dependency injection with an IoC, for example Unity. Register your IAccountContext with an InjectionFactory which would be a simple method that would run the code you already have to get the connection string based on the User.Identity.GetUserId() and create the AccountContext passing the discovered connection string.

I don't know if you are familiar with what I am saying or not. If you need it I can write more detailed instructions.

Comment: Nor really familiar with IoC and would love to see a bit more detailed instructions to get me going. Also I added an edit to the question

Comment: Also I just added the stack trace