# Using different connection name depending on the user that logs in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

It is the exact same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33454223/setting-the-contexts-connection-name-depending-on-the-user-that-logs-in) but, this time I'm using MVC6 and EF7 so the situation is completely different.

I was looking at the approaches [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Configuring-a-DbContext#dependency-injection-scenarios) but I am lost.

I have 6 connection strings and I defined them all in the `appsettings.json` file. Depending on the user, I would grab his connection string name from the users database and use it for the data database, but at this point I can't see how can I do it without going the nonDI path.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

DbContext's connection string can be configured with `DbContextOptions`.

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public BloggingContext (DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
}
```

You could go the non-DI route, or you could create a DI service that calls this constructor and inject that DI service instead of the DbContext directly. You might write something like this:

```
public class BloggingContextFactory
{
    public void Create(UserAccount userAccount)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(userAccount.ConnectionString);

        return new BloggingContext(optionsBuilder.Options);

    }
}

// in Startup.ConfigureServices

        .AddSingleton(new BloggingContextFactory());


// once injection
public class Controller
{
    public Controller(BloggingContextFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // ...
        using(var db = _factory.Create(userAccount))
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```